# Como puedo pasar codigo javascript a TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Necesito implementar este codigo en TypeScript pero realmente no se mucho de javascript por lo cual no tengo idea de como hacerlo les agradeceria mucho si me colaboran
Este es un metodo para realizar pagos la herramienta que utilizare se llama stripe y la verdad todo lo que hace es con javascript puro

```js
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('api_key');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

```css
/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 40px;

  padding: 10px 12px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido sebas. Por tu etiqueta parece que estas trabajando con angular. Es importante resaltar lo que habitualmente se hace es pasar el código de typescript a javascript, y que si el typado y la sintaxis te lo permite el código debería correr igual, caso contrario tendrías problemas con algunos errores al no reconocer algunas funciones que seguramente haces uso desde el enlace de stripe... Sea como sea no es conveniente hacer lo que buscas. Pará dar solución a tu caso deberías hacer uso de los módulos de stripe para su uso en angular.

Comment: Te dejo este enlace para más información:   https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe-angular                Como sugerencia: no intentes convertir un código, sino usa las herramientas dedicadas específicamente para angular

Comment: No necesitas transformar tu codigo JavaScript a Typescript ya que TS es un set de herramientas que se deriva de JS, por lo que todo el codigo JS deberia funcionar sin necesitar conversion. Ahora bien, si al compilar tu codigo TS te esta generando errores deberias revisar dichos errores e irlos modificando uno a uno.

Comment: Dato de vital importancia: AngularJS es la versión 1.x donde utiliza JavaScript, Angular de la versión 2.x a la actual 8.x hace uso de TypeScript.